# ASP.Net Gridview edit, update with dynamic item template header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Scenarios:

Based on selection of a dropdown value and click of search button gridview to be binded. This datatable will have different table/column records based on selected value of a dropdown.

For ex :

If dropdown list value "Yes" is selected Column 1 to Column 6 to be bounded from table A where column 1 is a check box , column 2 is a bound field and column 3,5,6 is a textbox and column 4 is a dropdown

If dropdown list value "No" is selected Column 1,Column 4 to Column 8 to be bounded from table A where column 1 is a check box , column 4 is a bound field and column 6,7,8 is a textbox and column 5 is a dropdown

I have to edit each records on by one and save it to a data table. on click of a final submit button the records to be saved in database

Comment: you have save searching data in Viewstate after you complete the edit you can submit the record with following id

Comment: Any sample code or url is appreciated

Comment: Please include your current code and what is the problem you have. If you don't have any code, then you're in the wrong place. SO is not a place for asking someone to give you code or provide tutorial links.